# ARM template for Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-rm-template

What should be the type under resources, if I want to create an ARM template for Azure Active Directory?

Is there any resources for adding User/Group/Application features in Azure Active Directory through ARM templates?

Answer (score 7):

Currently, there is *no* way to *programmatically* provision an Azure Active Directory. Thus, there is also *no* ARM templates available for that.

You have to use either, the [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-graph-api) (REST) or a PowerShell Module like [AzureAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view-azureadps-2.0=&view=azureadps-2.0) to create User / Application for an *existing* AAD.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure there is none, looking at the Azure ARM schema I don't see anything Azure AD related. You can look at the [ARM Schema here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-resource-manager-schemas/blob/master/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json).